# Accessing props from child element as a parameter in React and ES6

Tags: javascript, svg, reactjs

I have a file called `Svg.js` that is structured like so:

```
const Svg =({children, height, width, className, ...otherProps}) => {
  return <svg width={width} height={height} viewBox={"0 0 " + vpWidth + " " + vpHeight} className={className} style={{height: height + "px", width: width + "px"}}>{children}</svg>
}

export default Svg
```

and is then used like this:

```
const icon = (
    <Svg width="25" height="23" vpHeight="23" vpWidth="25" className="nav-icon">
        {React.createElement(brandingConfig.svgs.Add)}
     </Svg>
)
```

(there is an imported file which has an object called `brandingConfig` in, with a child object called `svgs`, which has the SVGs for the brand imported, in this example, one called `Add.js`, code below).

I have individual SVGs defined in JS(X) files like this (which are imported into brandingConfigs, as explained above):

```
import React from 'react'

const Add = ({}) => {
  // return SVG code
}

export default Add
```

So all this works great and renders the SVGs. However, I need to be able to change the SVGs on the web app to fit a new brand. I want to be able to keep the width and height of the actual icons the same across different brands, but SVG also has a `viewBox` property, which defines the canvas size and position etc. These values will be different for each brand. I would rather this was defined in the individual SVG file (`Add.js`) as it needs to be kept constant.

**So how would I define `vpWidth` and `vpHeight` in the file where the SVG code is and then access it in the Svg.js file, rather than when the `<Svg />` element is called? I need to keep the `{React.createElement(brandingConfig.svgs.Add)}` the same as well.**